# Calling measure() on child views more than once

Tags: android, layout

There's something in android docs:

> A parent View may call measure() more than once on its children. For example, the parent may measure each child once with unspecified dimensions to find out how big they want to be, then call measure() on them again with actual numbers if the sum of all the children's unconstrained sizes is too big or too small (that is, if the children don't agree among themselves as to how much space they each get, the parent will intervene and set the rules on the second pass).

sdk/docs/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

i don't undrestand; can somebody says what is he saying?
why does some view call measure() more than once on it's childs?
what's happening in LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text so that width is not zero"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Lets take a look how width is calculated :

When the parent has wrap_content and the child also has wrap_content. This is what happens,

First parent is measured. Since width is wrap_content width of parent will be 0 (no padding for parent).

Now the child will be measured. Lets say its a TextView with some text. Now the textview has something so its width can be measured.(say 100dp)

Again now the parent will be measured, this time it has a child with width of 100dp. So now the parent width becomes 100dp.

If we use match_parent this multiple passes at the parent level can be avoided. But its not the case always. I hope that i made my point clear, if not let me know.